# monogame.extended.entities no world in namespace`

Tags: monogame

VS 2017, monogame project, pulled in the MonoGame.Extended.Entities dependency.  I went to the class browser and I don't see the world object.  I can see it's apart of the code on github and should be there.

I installed the dependency through the nuget manager in vs 2017.

using version 1.1.0 MonoGame.Extended.Entities

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. The demos on their GitHub page all function normally, and they reference the source code, not the nuget packages, so the night versions are lacking . The 1.1.0 nuget version doesn't appear to match the GitHub version 1.1.0, which is a little unusual. I fixed it by updating the packages to the prerelease version. The method I used can be found in their docs:

http://docs.monogameextended.net/NuGet-Pre-Release/